# Erro com Asp.NET Web.API + AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Tenho meu método `C#` assim

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Categoria))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Categoria model) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    if (_repositorio.InsertOrUpdate(model, out Res)) {
        _repositorio.Save();
        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = model.Id }, model);
    }
    return BadRequest("Erro ao tentar salvar, tente novamente mais tarde");    
}
```

Tenho minha `factory` assim:

```
.factory("categoriasService", function($http, config, $q) {
    var _postItem = function(record) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post(config.baseUrl + "/api/Categoria/Post", record).then(
            function(result) {
                deferred.resolve(result.data);
            },
            function (erroResult) {
                deferred.reject();
            }
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    return {            
        postItem: _postItem
    };
})
```

Ao chamar em meu *controller*:

```
.controller("newCategoriaCtrl", [
    "$scope", "$http", "$window", "categoriasService", "modalConfirmationService", "$routeParams",
    function ($scope, $http, $window, categoriasService, modalConfirmationService, $routeParams) {            
        if ($routeParams.id !== undefined) {
            categoriasService.find($routeParams.id).then(function (result) {
                $scope.newCategoria = result;
            });
            $scope.titleAcao = "Alterar";
        } else {
            $scope.newCategoria = { Id: 0 };
            $scope.titleAcao = "Cadastrar";
        }

        $scope.save = function() {
            //console.log($scope.newCategoria);
            categoriasService.postItem($scope.newCategoria)
            .then(function (newCategoria) {
                console.log(newCategoria);//aqui o objeto está sempre vazio por que acontece o erro 500.
                modalConfirmationService.getModalInstance("Sucesso", "Dados salvos com sucesso!");
            },
            function() {
                modalConfirmationService.getModalInstance("Erro", "Não foi possível executar sua ação, tente novamente mais tarde.");
            })
            .then(function() {
                $window.location = "#";
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

Quando chamo a aplicação, sem ativar o debug no console do navegador, sempre ocorre erro 500 e não salva a informação na base de dados.

`http://localhost:54100/api/Categoria/Post 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Mas se eu ativar o modo debug no VS, dá o mesmo erro no console, mas a informação é salva na base de dados.

O que está errado? Tenho que configurar algo na app web.api?

Comment: Para não ocorrer nenhum erro no modo DEBUG, provavelmente seus exceptions podem estar desabilitados.

tente habilitar
NO VS, DEBUG -> WINDOWS -> EXCEPTION SETTINGS
e Habilite o C++ Exceptions, 
Common Langugages RunTimeExceptions
e GPU Memomy Access Exception

Answer (score 0):

Apenas com as informações acima fica difícil ajudar, porém o erro 500 acontece, por que você não tem um tratamento especifico p/ retornar o erro para tela, ou seja. na versão DEBUG do VS. seu controller (webApi) está sendo chamado. porém 
provavelmente na hora de executar essa linha de codigo

`return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = model.Id }, model);` deve esta estourando um erro, com isso o erro que retorna para o client é o 500 Logo que não existe um tratamento, o que costumo utilizar é um tratamento de erro

Try{}catch(){}. onde devolvo um objeto de `HttpResponseMessage` com o status tratado por mim, e uma exception p/ receber na client e realizar os tratamentos.

Comment: Não.. ao debugar utilizando VS, não acontece erro nenhum. O interessante é que so funciona a primeira chamda, depois para de funcionar. ao chamar o link direto.

Comment: Realmente não vai estourar um erro no VS, ele devolve esse 'erro', na response com status 500 entende ? se você colocar um try catch no seu método provavelmente vai pegar o que está acontecendo.

Comment: OK, vou testar com o try e te dou um retorno. Por enquanto obrigado!